# How to prevent videos to load in website

Tags: css, video

i have video on my side and i don't want it to load when the screen is too small, so i've tried this:

```
<video class="video-background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted"       volume="0">
  <source class="source-webm" type="video/webm"> 
  <source class="source-mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
  Video not supported 
</video>
```

css:

```
.source-mp4{
  content: url("PATH");
}
.source-webm{
  content: url("PATH");
}
@media screen and (max-width:300px){
  .source-mp4, .source-webm{
    content:none;
  }
}
```

it worked with image please help.

Comment: if youre sure `@media screen and (max-width:300px)` is working correctly, can you wrap your video in a `div` and give it a classname of `videoDiv`, then in css you can `.videoDiv{ display:none;}`

Answer (score -1):

Kindly Try this css

```
@media screen and (max-width:300px){
   video{
       display:none;
    }

}
```

Comment: if i use display:none; it will still load the video

Comment: this wouldn't prevent video from loading.